# How to get the key from a TDictionary?

Tags: delphi, tdictionary

I have a `TDictionary<TKeyClass, TValueClass>`.

I want to accomplish something like

```
for i := 0 to MyDictionary.Count -1 do
  ShowMessage(MyDictionary.Keys[i].AStringProperty)
```

I cannot Access the Keys anymore I can just use them if I exactly know them.

Is the only alternative create a `TDictionary<TValueClass, TKeyValue>` ? So I can loop thorugh the Keys?

The workaroud I found is to create a `TList<TKeyClass>` but this is something i don't like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an enumerator.

```
for Key in MyDictionary.Keys do
  ShowMessage(Key.AStringProperty);
```

Since TDictionary is a hash table, you can't access it with integer indexing like an array or TList. But an enumerator works just fine.